# Rails + Devise: forcing password reset upon initial login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

(NOTE: I've searched (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rails+devise+password+force) already, and there are several similar questions, but none of the answers seem right for me.)

How do you force a user to reset their password on initial sign-in using the `devise` gem? I wanted to require first-time users to change their password in `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :check_password_reset, only: [:create]

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.needs_password_reset
      password_path(current_user)
    else
      root_path
    end
  end

  protected

  def check_password_reset
    # have also tried:
    # if current_user && current_user.needs_password_reset
    if current_user && current_user.sign_in_count == 1
      flash[:alert] = "You must change your password now."
      redirect_to edit_user_password_path
    end
  end

end
```

But upon initial login, nobody is being prompted to change their password.

For additional reference, here is what is in `user.rb`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :rememberable, :trackable, :lockable,
         :database_authenticatable, :timeoutable,
         :recoverable

  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions.to_hash)
        .where(["name = :value OR email = :value",
                { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    elsif conditions.has_key?(:name) || conditions.has_key?(:email)
      where(conditions.to_h).first
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: But you have before_action only at create method, so when user just accessing some ```GET``` methods you will not check password.
Also do you want to restrict user access whole site until he do not set password?

Comment: Vasily, the `create` method is for the session; and the users are invite-only, which means that yes, the entire site is restricted until they get the password.